# how to create huge 2D arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to create a huge 2D array in c++ like this :

`float array[1000000][3];`
I have to store some values in this array which has 3 components. This will be done iteratively by two for loops of 1000 loops.
When I try to run this I get an error :

`Segmentation fault`

Here is a bit of my code :

```
int m=0,c=0;
float error;int count=0;
array<array<float, 1000000>, 3> errors;
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<1000; j++){
        error=distance(j+20,m,c,1000-matrix(1,j));
        errors[count][0]=error; 
        errors[count][1]=m; 
        errors[count][2]=c;
        c++;
        count++;
    }
    m++;
    c=0;
}                                        
sort(errors.begin(), errors.end());
cout<<errors[0][0]<<endl<<errors[0][1]<<endl<<errors[0][2]<<endl;
```

The error continues even after commenting out the sort...

matrix(1,j) is a matrix and I am accessing its elements using this method.

I want minimum value of error and the set of values of m and c for which error is minimum.

Is there any way I can achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use std::vector<> instead.

Comment: `1000000 * 3 * 4bytes = 12000000 bytes / (2^20)  > 11 MB`... That's a lot on the stack. As @drescherjm, points out, you are better off using `std::vector<float>`. See this for reference: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/310658

Comment: Consider using a smaller array unless you absolutely need all those values in memory *at the same time*.  Remember, all those values won't fit into the processor's data cache.

Comment: Consider using a single `vector` of a class containing 3 elements.  This will allow the three elements to be in the same processor data cache line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array` to easily perform your task. Here what you can:

```
#include<array>
using namespace std;
```

Then, let create your data array:

```
const int N = 1000000;
const int M = 3;
array<array<float, N>, M> my_array;
```

You can fill this newly created array by doing:

```
for(int i=0; i < N; i++){
    for(int j=0; j < M; j++){
        my_array[i][j] = 0.0f;  // Just for example
    }
}
```

For more information on how to use `array` library, please see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/)

If you don't want to use `array`, you can also proceed as follows:

```
const int N = 10000000;
const int M = 3;
float *my_array

my_array = new float[N*M];  // give it a memory on the stack
if(my_array == nullptr){
     cerr << "ERROR: Out of memory" << endl;
}

for(int i=0; i < N; i++){
    for(int j=0; j < M; j++){
        *(my_array + i*N + j) = 0.0f;  // Just for example
    }
}
```

Make sure you release the memory you acquired by doing:

```
delete [] my_array;
```

Comment: This suffers from the exact same problem as OPs code, it is not a solution

Comment: That is the reason why I suggested std::vector over std::array

Comment: Same `Segmentation fault`

Comment: `new float[N*M];  // give it a memory on the stack` is a completely wrong statement. global operator `new` allocates in dynamic memory (which is often times implemented as a heap). And why would you suggest using `new[]` and `delete[]` over `std::vector`?

Comment: Sorry, but the format you provided will not do the work... I want the minimum value of error and corresponding to that m and c [ refer to the ques. ]